# How to invoke Java file methods from JSP file in a Tomcat 8 project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I have a Tomcat 8 project in Eclipse, and I have JSP files within it that need to access variables populated in a Java file, using get() methods.  All of the variables need to be loaded on server startup, so I am using a ServletContextListener.  For some reason, I am not able to invoke the Java methods from the JSP pages, even though I am importing the Java file.  The error is "The method mymethod() is undefined for the type fileName.JSP".  My best guess is that I put the Java file in an invalid location for this project.  Right now I have it in Java Resources/src/com.mypackage/Java File.  Also, my JSP files are all in Webcontent/WEB-INF.  If someone could help me figure out what I might be doing wrong, I'd be greatly appreciative.  Thanks so much!

Comment: 1/ don't put jsp files under WEB-INF 
2/ paste your code

Comment: Sounds like an import issue on the JSP. Show us the JSP.

Comment: This doesn't sound like how imports work in Java.